# UPS on DC lines

Tags: power-supply, relay, ups

How could a UPS switch between battery and AC wall socket fast from around 4 ms to 12 ms. What make it especial to switch in that very low time. As far as I know it has relays inside it to perform the switching action, but the relay itself can't switch as fast. I am asking this because I need something to switch between 2 DC lines and I tried multiple 12 V DC relays to 30 amps ones and my devices still has to switch off or to reboot once the main DC power source cutt so the backup can't keep up.

I have a DC power system and AC one. The DC works as the backup batteries and the AC is the city power which I don't care about consumed watts from it, but what I care about is every watt from my batteries as 70% of time I am on batteries.

I have a mini DC gaming rig with 60 watts GTX 1060 and low powered I3 8th gen and my total consumption is around 110 watts per hour. The PC is meant to work on battery systems as his input voltage is from 6 to 36 voltage wide input range and can use 250 watts max components.
I already own an AC to DC 12 V adpater 300 watts to power it up, but I don't want it to switch off every time I lose the city power suddenly and I would like to keep it on so I bought a bunch of relays to switch between the AC to DC 12 V adapter and the 12 V battery system but none of them worked properly so I refunded them as the PC has to shutdown or restart at every power switching.

Note that of course I won't use inverter, switch the internal power supply to another AC power supply and use normal UPS to increase my power consumption to double of what I already have..... so please don't suggest AC stuff

Comment: Why not use a real UPS? Or add a fairly large capacitor, say 22,000uF @25v directly across the 12v supply. Add a current-sense resistor to it of 0.1Ω.  Use a high-side or low-side current monitor across the resistor, and have *that* toggle the relay. Because the capacitor will help "ride through" a power loss by momentarily providing the missing power, but when it starts sourcing power, the relay kicks in. Sounds like a fun project, but we do not do whole projects here.

Comment: Instead of using relays you simply could source the PC from multiple sources using diodes.

Comment: real UPS does not work on DC. it is on AC, but you actually answered my main question part that UPS has large capacitors to prevent power loss during the switch. Thx for that, but why choosing 22,000 uF 25v one? How did you measure that and why 0.1 ohm and why not writing that as a detaild answer dude. You already have what I need to know and that diode I really don't know what these stuff does but I can assemble them if you give me instructions

Comment: @Tom Kuschel I actually don't want the AC to DC adapter to apply voltages and current on the battery and her charger as one group so will that diode prevent it?

Comment: Why do you not run the computer constantly on 12V, and use a smart charger on the batteries? This prevents the use of any relays, etc. The batteries will be maintained when AC power is active, and if there's a power cut it will discharge the batteries.

Comment: Yes the diode will prevent it to charge the battery. You'll need 300 W/12 V = 25 A diodes, and to reduce the voltage drop you should use Schottky diodes (hot-carrier diodes) instead of standard silicium diodes. Also think about fuse protection of the battery!

Comment: @Natsu Kage as far as I know the smart charger won't know how to charge properly if there is any load applied on the batteries (not sure). It will force high current at bulk charge phase damaging the batteries if the PC was turned off. However the charger will extend first bulk phase and constant voltage phase and never enter the float charging phase if the pc is running at full load. In other words the charger will think that I am using much higher battery capacity than what I already own.

Answer (score 0):

What you are experiencing a loss of power during switchover between power sources. In your case you have 2 DC power sources and 1 DC power consumer and the power consumer(your gaming rig) accepts a wider input voltage.
The simplest solution could be make grounds of your rig, and both power supplies common. On the positive(+) output of each your power sources you could put a large diode(40Amps stud diodes come in cheap). The anode(+) of these each diode would be connected to your power sources and the cathode(-) of both these diodes would be connected together and form the common positive for your power consumer(gaming rig). The diodes would ensure that power from one source doesn't flow back into the other and this whenever power from any one of the sources is available your computer would stay powered on. 
Now while this solution solves your changeover problem, it doesn't help you prioritize power delivery from one of the sources when both are ready to supply power. Additionally diodes waste power as a voltage drop occurs whenever they are conducting current. In your case your current could be as high as 10Amps. Depending on the diode forward bias voltage at 10Amps, this could mean around 1V of voltage drop and thus around 10W of power loss on the diodes and thats why your diodes will need a heat sink plate to allow then to stay cool.

Now there could be a bit more complex solution that would waste less power and this would involve using diodes only during changeover and using relay/mosfets to avoid constant power loss in the diodes all the time.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Lets say that I raized up the voltage of first source to more than 15V so that the second source (batteries) is always bellow 15V. This means the first power source should charge the other source, but if I put a large diode on the second source cathode (+) (batteries) so the first source won't charge the batteries, but it will instead go immediately to load. I think that would prevent the batteries from flowing while the first source is available because it has a higher voltage since my PC accepts wide input voltage. Should this work? Can you explain the combination of relay and diode?